# MySQL InnoDB locking

Tags: locking, innodb, myisam

I have 2 connections.
1st connection makes query:

```
UPDATE table1 SET column1 = 5;
```

2nd connection:

```
SELECT t1.column1, t2.column2
FROM table2 t2
JOIN table1 t1 
     ON t1.column1 = t2.column1
```

table1 - InnoDB, table2 - MyISAM

MySQL server gets 2nd query immidiatly after getting 1st query. Would the query in 2nd connection wait until update is done?

Comment: I think it depends on the isolation levels, first has a write lock, the second can read some dirty data or wait, depends on the settings (Isolation levels)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming isolation level other than `SERIALIZABLE` (default is `REPEATABLE READ`), the second query won't wait for the first, but will read the data from the rollback log instead.

You can verify this by starting a transaction, performing an update and then sleeping for several seconds in one thread, and performing the second query while the first is sleeping in another